# "Archives" section not present in git hub repository setting

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, archive, git-lfs, hub

I want to include a unity file on git hub. To upload a unity file git-lfs is needed, so we have to enable the include git-lfs under the archive section but the archive section is not found in my repository:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbiC2.png)

I am searching for the solution to this problem online but have not been able to find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I meet the same problem. git lfs file not included in archive, so I find the Github doc [enter link description here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/managing-git-lfs-objects-in-archives-of-your-repository) tells me in Settings-Archive can enable it. So I found it in the Settings page, you can check it